# Book Identification: Choose Your Own Adventure style book with a dog that turns out to be a secret agent for planet Sirius

Tags: story-identification, books, choose-your-own-adventure

I remember reading this book as a kid in the early 1990s. It was Choose Your Own Adventure in style, but I don't know if it was actually CYOA brand.

From what I recall it was targeted towards middle grade reading. It sounds somewhat similar in concept to R. A. Montgomery's "Lost Dog!", but there's a big plot point missing in all the summaries I read online for that book: It turns out, depending on your choices, that you discover your "dog" is actually an alien from Sirius, and is a secret agent. This plot could lead to discovering that the "dog house" was actually a spaceship, and could travel back to Sirius.

Various other endings I remember included getting knocked out in an alley or something similar.

It was a paperback.

Comment: As well as "Lost Dog!" there is a series of three books in the CYOA Young Readers series that feature a different protagonist and his dog - in the third, Space Pup, you do go into space with the dog - but that was published in 2014. (From what I can gather, the CYOA Young Readers books that feature you and your dog Homer go The Haunted House, Return to Haunted House, Space Pup. The first is from the 80s, but the latter two are from the 2010s.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is ["Dog Food & Other Delights"](https://gamebooks.org/Item/1706/Show) by Susan M. Zitzman.

[image] [image]

According to [Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Dog_Food_Other_Delights/SU0ma64nXL4C) and [Demian's Gamebook Web Page](https://gamebooks.org/Item/1706/Show) it was published in 1987, which fits in well with your reading it in the early 90s.

It is a CYOA-style book - the back cover scan above talks about you making choices, and the Google Books snippet below shows you having to make an "If you do Z, turn to paragraph W" choices:

[image]

By the way, the dog isn't *from* Sirius - his *name is* Sirius:

[image] [image]

As for discovering that the dog house was actually a spaceship - initially even Sirius doesn't know it!

[image]

But, eventually, the two of you work it out:

[image]

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much!